# How to give UIImageView attributes using if/else function?

Tags: swift, function

How can I trim this function down to be as lean as possible? The only difference between the if and else blocks is the height of the UiImageView--if true, height is 300, else 150. I can't seem to figure out the best way to refactor this function without either redundant code (like in the example) or with a really long function that just seems way too long for something that seems rather simple.

I left the example crude to make the intention clear.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        banner(profileHasCustomBanner: false)

    }

    // banner
    func banner(profileHasCustomBanner: Bool) {
        if profileHasCustomBanner == true {
            let bannerImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 300))
            bannerImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "the-banner")
            view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            view.addSubview(bannerImageView)
        } else {
            let bannerImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 150))
            bannerImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "the-banner")
            view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            view.addSubview(bannerImageView)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a `height` variable based on the condition.

```
func banner(profileHasCustomBanner: Bool) {
    let height: CGFloat = profileHasCustomerBanner ? 300 : 150
    let bannerImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height))
    bannerImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "the-banner")
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(bannerImageView)
}
```

Comment: @maddy what object is view.contentMode attributed to? When I write it as self.view.contentMode, it compiles, but doesn't compile with any other object, so what exactly is self right here?

Comment: `view` and `self.view` refer to the same thing - the current view controller's view.

Comment: But there can be many views in the view controller. If I created another banner just below this banner and I wanted its contentMode to be .scaleAspectFill, how is that specific view referred to?

Comment: Yes, but `UIViewController` has one and only one property named `view`. See the documentation for `UIViewController`.

Comment: So view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit will apply this attribute to all views within this UIViewController and not just that specific banner UIImageView?

Comment: It applies to the top level view of the view controller.